# Нужна программа в установщике Windows Installer. Где ее найти?

Tags: windowsinstaller

Нужна программа зашитая в установщик Windows Installer и при этом небольшого размера.

Работаю с WMI, событиями WMI в частности. Стоит задача отлавливать событие установки нового ПО (класс WIN32_Product, для тех кто в теме). И проблема в том, что это событие генерируется только при установке программ с Windows Installer.

*Из комментариев:* Мне нужна ЛЮБАЯ готовая программа с инсталляцией из MSI-пакета для тестов моего (уже написанного) кода. Где ее взять?

Comment: Если вы хотите отлавливать запуск произвольного инсталлятора, то если он не дергает WindowsInstaller у вас нет способа отличить такой  инсталлятор от любой другой программы. А вообще, опишите более общую задачу, которую пытаетесь решить

Comment: ну собственно мне и нужно чтобы "дергался" Windows Installer. Если говорить как в ТЗ - обеспечивать проверку наличия нового инсталлированного ПО т.е установилось новое ПО - сгенерировалось событие - выпало оповещение, а событие генерируется только Windows Installer`ом

Comment: Может стоит следить за реестром? Не вариант?

Comment: Задача стоит именно через WMI это делать

Comment: либо автор ТЗ не понимает как это работает, либо одно из двух. Можно через WMI следить за реестром удаленных машин. Но опять же, не любое ПО пишет себя в реестр, в последнее время довольно популярны портабельные версии ПО, им вообще пофиг на систему, тупо копируешь в папку и работаешь, не нужно - удалил папку, или вообще не копируешь, а работаешь с флешки. Так что панацеи тут нет, во всяком случае на десктопе.

Comment: вообще подобные задачи решаются на уровне администрирования. Пользователям запрещено устанавливать что либо и запускать программы из произвольных папок, а вопросы распространения необходимого ПО перекладываются на групповые политики. Но для этого нужен хотя бы один вменяемый админ и железобетонная поддержка такой жесткой политики со стороны руководства безотносительно должностей пользователей. Единые правила для всех, иначе только геморроя добавится. Исключение может составлять только IT-отдел (админы и разрабы) ибо это их работа.

Comment: Отлично понимаю вашу точку зрения, но однако вопрос все еще в силе: где найти программу на Windows Installer?

Comment: WindowsInstaller пишет все свои события в системный лог (поле источник = MsiInstaller). Заставить произвольные инсталляторы писать что либо куда либо если они сами этого не делают возможности нет.

Comment: или вам нужно чтобы ваша программа при установке дергала WindowsSinstaller? Тогда вам нужно просто сформировать *.MSI пакет вместо обычного setup.exe или что там у вас сейчас.

Comment: @rdorn да, именно. Собственно нашел себе такой msi-пакет - Orca.msi. Благодяpю за ответы.

Comment: Так вам нужна была любая программа с инсталляцией из MSI-пакета для тестов вашего кода? Так бы и написали в вопросе.

Comment: ээээ...ну окей, ладно, допустим я написал не так...=\